# Can't Execute jar files

Tags: java, files, jar

I'm having trouble opening jar files because there is no java runtime in open with listed. Even I have installed it via Software Center(i also try to reinstall it via synaptic and i do a --purge via terminal).

Comment: What did you install? It should have been OpenJDK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just recently had the same problem - the way I fixed it was to **uninstall OpenJDK 7 and install OpenJDK 6**.

I have no idea why OpenJDK 7 doesn't want to work but it started glitching when I installed it via the Terminal.

Installing OpenJDK 6 is like installing a fresh new version of Java.

I had tried many different other commands and they didn't seem to work.

Comment: I believe he said he'd tried that already.

Comment: @IanLantzy, I thought the OP said that they reinstalled the one that they downloaded beforehand - not mentioning a downgrade, as I suggested.

Comment: My bad, for some reason I read the bolded text as just uninstalling and reinstalling openjdk 6 and 7.

Comment: No problemo =3 I read things (especially commands) wrong every now and then.

Comment: Ty i did something similar, i just installed jdk8 runtime, now i can execute Jar files :D

Comment: @lutbaZion No problemo! ;)

Answer (score 3):

Right click - properties
Click on the "Permissions" tab and make sure the "Allow executing file as program" checkbox is checked.

Comment: I always forget about giving x permissions. Solved! Thank you! (not sarcasm)

Answer (score 2):

You can also use terminal;

```
java -jar /home/al0s/Downloads/asd.jar
```

without installing new things.

Comment: Already had OracleJDK installed, its great to see a solution without any additional installation.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Open a terminal and try running

```
java -version
```

As long as it returns something, you have java installed. You likely haven't marked the .jar files as executable. To do so open a terminal, navigate to where the .jar files are located and run

```
chmod u+x name-of-file.jar
```

Replacing `name-of-file.jar` with the .jar file you're wanting to run.

Answer (score 1):

I actually had this problem, too. I had Java installed and marked the `jar` as executable, but it still didn't work. Here's how I fixed it (kind of a workaround):

1. Right-click on the `jar` you want to open and select `Properties`.
2. Click `File Type Options`, under the `Type` section.
3. Click `Add` under the `Application Preference Order` and search `jar`.
4. Select the result, `jar`, in the dropdown menu and click `OK`.
5. Click `jar` in the `Application Preference Order` list and click `Edit`.
6. Go to the `Application` tab and enter `java -jar` as the command.
7. OK out of everything and you should now be able to double-click any `jar` to open it.

Answer (score 0):

> Create sh file in same directory, i am making sample file for jar file "test.jar"
>
> ---
>
> Filename: test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
java -jar test.jar
```

> Give rights for execution

```
chmod +555 test.sh
```

> now you can execute your jar with double click on test.**sh**, you can make link at another places also of test.**sh**

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it should +555 or +777

Comment: no prob, right click on sh file, Properties > Permissions > check Allow execution..

Comment: it's nothing but just give rights for execution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83320/discussion-between-dharmendrasinh-chudasama-and-perlduck).