# Confused as to the procedure to install a java application

Tags: 18.04

New to Ubuntu, using 18.04.

I'm trying to work out the best procedure for installing jwildfire flame fractal software. If you're interested go here http://jwildfire.org/

The install is just a bunch of files in a .zip file that just need to be unpacked into a directory. The app is launched by executing the j-wildfire-launcher.jar

Question 1 - Where should this be unpacked to, and why?

Question 2 - How to do this?

I've trawled through a bunch of forums and there seems to be no clear consensus as to where things should be installed. Many people say 'just let the installer choose the right place' but this has no installer, it's just a zip file with a java executable.  When I try to use the Archive manager to unpack it into /opt or some such it throws a permissions error.

Any help appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [How can I execute a .jar file from the terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101746/how-can-i-execute-a-jar-file-from-the-terminal) and [Can't Execute jar files](https://askubuntu.com/q/615082)

Answer (score 0):

## Question 1:

There is no definite answers of where to install, but if you want suggestion, I recommend place it to `/home/<user>/j-wild-fire` (replace `<user>` to your `username`) rather than `/opt`, since `/opt` require `sudo` permission to write, this is the reason why you can't create file inside `/opt`. If you want more about what `sudo` is, you can read [this](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/sudo-beginners-guide/).

## Question 2:

- 1. open the terminal by press `ctrl`+`alt`+`t`
- 2. install `unzip` and `java` if necessary, by enter the following command in terminal

```sh
sudo apt install unzip
sudo apt install default-jre
```

- 3. unzip the file

```sh
unzip <location_of_your_zip_file> -d /home/<user>/j-wild-fire
```

- 4. run the program

```sh
java -jar /home/<user>/j-wild-fire/j-wildfire-launcher.jar
```

- 5. If you want to create launcher, you can follow [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/854373/how-to-create-a-desktop-shortcut), and use the command in step.4

Comment: Up to point 3 this works fine.  At point 4 I get an error "Error: unable to access jarfile j-wildfire-launcher.jar"

Comment: It seems its bash script doesn't use relative path. I have change the command in step 4 using absolute path, it should works now.

Comment: hmmmm.... well that sort of worked, but now there's a different problem that I don't understand.  The launcher works, but it won't launch the program.  In the launcher there's a message log tab that says "No JRE found in "/home/<user>/j-wildfire/j-wildfire-launcher.jar".  I really don't know what this message means or how to solve it.

Comment: Can you try to replace `java` to `/usr/bin/java`?

Comment: How would I do that?